# How to extract a substring from a random string?

Tags: c#, string

I have strings similar to these:

> TAMPA HQ - 9125 Henderson Rd - Comment Posted on Work Order # 7065
>
> TAMPA HQ - 9125 Henderson Rd - Work Order # 79651 Alert
>
> TAMPA HQ - 9125 Henderson Rd - Work Order # 805923 Request Number Assigned

**Is there any generic way to extract WO #?** in C# so the output would be:

> Work Order # 7065
>
> Work Order # 79651
>
> Work Order # 805923

etc?

Comment: Have you tried Regex?

Comment: Will all strings have "Work Order # " in them?

Comment: Nope, I am not proficient with Regex, so if you want to suggest something that would help me a lot. Note The actual WO number can be any number of digits.

Comment: Yes, Raj,  all strings have "Work Order # " plus the actual number after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex would work: `Work Order # \d+`.

```
Regex r = new Regex("Work Order # \d+");
Match match = r.Match("TAMPA HQ - 9125 Henderson Rd - Work Order # 79651 Alert");
```

Comment: Since I suck at regex, maybe you can help me out to get value "WO-134261" from a string "Comcast Center Facility Service Request # WO-134261" ?

Comment: will this do? `Request # WO-\d+`

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this:

```
"^Work Order #.\d+"
```

Comment: `^` will cause it to not match the examples given (the first 3)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm:

```
LengthOfString = StrLength (IncomingString)
WorkOrderNumberPosition = FindInString (IncomingString, "Work Order # ")
LeftSideRemovedString = SubString (IncomingString, WorkOrderNumberPosition, LengthOfString - WorkOrderNumberPosition)
WorkOrderRemoved = Replace (LeftSideRemovedString, "Work Order #", "")
```

Now, loop through and find the last consecutive character that is a number, and use that number to do a substring.

Answer (score 0):

```
//to simulate an input lines
var input = new StringBuilder();
input.AppendLine("TAMPA HQ -9125 Henderson Rd -Comment Posted on Work Order # 7065");
input.AppendLine("TAMPA HQ -9125 Henderson Rd -Work Order # 79651 Alert");
input.AppendLine("TAMPA HQ - 9125 Henderson Rd -Work Order # 805923 Request Number Assigned");

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<Identifier>Work Order # \d+)");
var results = regex.Matches(input.ToString());
foreach (Match match in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["Identifier"].Value);
}
```

tested here : http://rextester.com/CAR42027